# Simplifying one-liner with sed and multiple awk calls

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, perl, bsd

I would like to simplify this one liner that will print only if a partition is greater than or equal to 60% utilization. I would also like to append a percent sign on to the utilization value.

```
df -h | sed 's/%//g' | awk '{print $6,$5 }' | awk '{ if($2 >=60 ) print}' | column -t
```

I am using a BSD variant and I do **not** have the common GNU tools installed.

Comment: Sorry about the title, first time user here. Both commands worked great thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged `awk` let us work on that. The first `awk` is just being used to move columns 6 and 5 to 1 and 2, so we can get rid of that and just use 6 and 5 in the second awk.

```
df -h | sed 's/%//g' | awk '{ if($5 >=60 ) print $6, $5 }' | column -t
```

We can add in the percent sign as well

```
df -h | sed 's/%//g' | awk '{ if($5 >=60 ) print $6, $5 "%"}' | column -t
```

We can remove the `sed` and do that within the awk

```
df -h | awk '{gsub(/%/,""); if($5 >=60) print $6, $5 "%"}' | column -t
```

We could remove the `column -t` by letting awk store the values in an array, and then in an `END` statement loop over the array to figure out the longest name and print accordingly, but this is no longer a `one liner` in my opinion.

Comment: EXCELLENT THANKS !!!  I am new with sed and awk so I really appreciate this. the last command failed but then I only have bourne shell and T shell. YOU ROCK !

Comment: @Steve how does the last command fail? It works for me. In general this script is a bit fragile as the output of `df -h` changes if you have remote filesystems with long names, which I didn't addess.

Comment: Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/da0s4d    248M     10K    228M     0%    /tmp
/dev/da0s2d    989M    293M    617M    32%    /usr
/dev/da0s4e     16G     57M     15G     0%    /var
/dev/da0s4f     55G    123M     50G     0%    /var/log
/dev/da0s4g     43G    122M     40G     0%    /var/spool
/dev/da0s1a    2.9G    845M    1.8G    31%    /vcdrom
Shakezula:Admn {7} % df -h | awk '{sub(/%/,"",$5); if($5 >=60) print $6, $5 "%"}' | column -t
Mounted  Capacity%
it doesnt have any output. Your other suggestions worked perfectly though,

Comment: df -h | awk '{sub(/%/,"",$5); if($5 >=60) print $6, $5 "%"}' | column -t
Mounted  Capacity%

Comment: This is all the output stated
Mounted  Capacity%

Comment: bourne shell and T shell, no BASH

Comment: @Steve, bash or no bash shouldn't matter. What appears to be going wrong is the sub command. I have tried this with gnu awk version 4.1.1, mawk 1.3.3 and busybox awk, and all work. Lets see if we can work around the issue - it might give you some insights into debugging awk. Try changing it to `awk '{gsub(/%/,""); print "F5=" $5; if($5>=60) print $6, $5 "%"}'` - this will remove all the percent marks rather than just removing them from the 5th field, and show the fifth field after it has done so.

Comment: df |awk '{gsub(/%/,""); print "F5=" $5; if($5>=60) print $6, $5 "%"}'
F5=Capacity
Mounted Capacity%
F5=23
F5=100
/dev 100%
F5=0
F5=40
F5=0
F5=32
F5=0
F5=0
F5=0
F5=31

Comment: Trying to share the ouput but its a bit messy. It did not come out right. I am new to awk other than simple print statements.

Comment: df -h | awk '{gsub(/%/,""); print if($5>=60) print $6, $5 "%"}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        {gsub(/%/,""); print >>>  if <<< ($5>=60) print $6, $5 "%"}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: you have an extra word `print` just before the `if`. You might consider changing the 60 to 30 as well for debugging, as your disks are not very full!

Comment: HOLY COW BOOM !!!!!!

Comment: df -h | awk '{gsub(/%/,""); if($5>=30) print $6, $5 "%"}'
Mounted Capacity%
/dev 100%
/secureos 40%
/usr 32%
/vcdrom 31%

Comment: I learned that you are a genius !!! But I am actively watching AWK tutorials . I have not seen gsub ever before. So, I have a LONG way to go yet.

Answer (score 2):

A bit easier with simple grep. Only the two columns won't be swapped.

```
$ df -h|egrep -o "(100|[6-9].)% /.*$"
65% /
93% /home
```

Comment: df -h | egrep -o "(100|[6-9].)% /.*$\"
Illegal variable name.

Comment: I ran it but it errored out                                                                                         df -h | egrep -o "(100|[6-9].)% /.*$\"
Illegal variable name.

Comment: @Steve: which shell do you use?

Comment: I use TCSH and bourne shell

Comment: `egrep -o` is a GNU extension. In general you should always use single quotes rather than double quotes unless you want the substitutions to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You may replace the `sed` with `tr -d "%"` and combine the two invocations of `awk` into a single one:

```
$ df -h | tr -d "%" | awk '$5 >= 60 { print $6, $5 }' | column -t
```

To get the percentage sign in:

```
$ df -h | tr -d "%" | awk '$5 >= 60 { printf("%s %s%s\n", $6, $5, (NR>1?"%":"")) }' | column -t
```

The second version of the Awk script conditionally adds a `%` to the second output column depending on whether `NR` is greater than one or not. If `NR` is one, we don't add a `%` since that's the header line.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `df` command has `--output` switch , which allows you to display only specific columns. Knowing that, and combining with knowledge that we can replace text in `awk`, the job becomes slightly easier:

```
$ df --output=source,pcent | awk '{gsub(/\%/," ");if($2 > 60) print}'                                                        
Filesystem     Use 
/dev/sda1       63
```

Python can do all that as well. As one-liner:

```
df --output=source,pcent | python -c "import sys;lines=sys.stdin.readlines();lines.pop(0);print [l.strip() for l in lines if int(l.replace('%',' ').split()[1]) > 60]"
```

Or as script for more readability:

```
bash-4.3$ cat filter_df.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys;
for index,line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if index == 0: continue
    if int(line.replace('%',' ').split()[1]) > 60 :
        print line
bash-4.3$ df --output=source,pcent | ./filter_df.py 
/dev/sda1       63%
```

Comment: df --output=source,pcent | awk '{gsub(/\%/," ");if($2 > 60) print}'
df: illegal option -- -
usage: df [-b | -g | -H | -h | -k | -m | -P] [-acilnT] [-t type] [file | filesystem ...]

Comment: @Steve what system are you using ? Notice that I mentioned GNU `df`. What is your `df --version` ?

Comment: Apparently an old one. I am new to AWK for the most part.     df --version
df: illegal option -- -
usage: df [-b | -g | -H | -h | -k | -m | -P] [-acilnT] [-t type] [file | filesystem ...]

Comment: @Steve well . . . that's peculiar. Does `df --help` say anything about the version ?   By the way, welcome to the ranks of AWK users ;)

Comment: Thank you !!! and nope, df --help
df: illegal option -- -
usage: df [-b | -g | -H | -h | -k | -m | -P] [-acilnT] [-t type] [file | filesystem ...]

Comment: @Steve are you using FreeBSD or some BSD variant ? Because freebsd man page is the only thing i found matching that set of switches and lacking the others we tried. Well, I guess this specific solution won't help you. I'll keep the post - Linux derivatives use GNU df for the most part

Comment: yes sir, BSD I am on

Answer (score 0):

If we can use Perl:

```
df | perl -nE 'say "$2\t$1"   if /(\d+)% (.*)/ and $1>60'
```

or

```
df | perl -nE '/(\d+)% (.*)/ and $1>60 and  say "$2\t$1"'
```

Comment: Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options).  I ran it but using bourne shell, not BASH, so that is likly my prob

Comment: @Steve, you probably have a very old Perl version...

Comment: And it will **not** be a bash vs sh issue.

Answer (score 0):

Show any partitions with more than 60% usage (either size or inodes):

```
df -h | grep '[67890].%'
```

it is that simple. 
(0 is there to catch the ones with 100℅)